# Imported image showing image path instead of the image - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tried importing an image but instead of displaying the image, it's displaying the path to the image instead.

The Array I'm creating, and I'm still adding more data to it is:

```
import importedImage from './assets/path.png';
export const membersData = {
    All: [
        { 
            id: 1,
            picture: importedImage,
            name: 'Demo name', 
            location: 'Demo location', 
            role: 'Consultant ', 
            contact: 'T: number \nE: mail' 
        },
    ],
}
```

How I rendered it:

```
{posts.length === 0 ? (
   <p>No posts...</p>
  ) : (
  posts.map((post) => (
   <div key={post.id}>
   {post.picture}
   </div>                       
)))}
```

result : `/static/media/path.aba65f86.png`

Note: **The path isn't what I've actually used, it's just for demonstration purposes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your bundler configured well, with import you should get a base64 image url.
So you can just pass it to the img tag:

```
<img src={post.picture} alt=""/>
```

Comment: If it's doesn't work can you share a screen how your URL looks like, and some information about app bundling (are you using create-react-app, or configuring bundler manually)?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add the `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Imported Image url to the image tag's src attribute.

```
<img src={post.picture} alt="Could not load image" />
```